# Python xlrd cell reading returns blank value

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, xls, xlrd

I am facing a weird problem during reading an xls file using xlrd package in python. The problem is xlrd returning most of the cells blank (while printing them or writting to a file) although it contains some (float and numeric) value. this is the code that I am using

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('299360.xls')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('sheet1')
num_rows = worksheet.nrows - 1
num_cells = worksheet.ncols - 1
curr_row = -1
while curr_row < num_rows:
    curr_row += 1
    row = worksheet.row(curr_row)
    print 'Row:', curr_row
    curr_cell = -1
    while curr_cell < num_cells:
        curr_cell += 1
        # Cell Types: 0=Empty, 1=Text, 2=Number, 3=Date, 4=Boolean, 5=Error, 6=Blank
        cell_type = worksheet.cell_type(curr_row, curr_cell)
        cell_value = worksheet.cell_value(curr_row, curr_cell)

        print ' ', cell_type, ':', cell_value
```

the strange thing is if I change,add or edit  any cell of the xls file and save it again, then I get all the cell values properly. Help me to solve this problem.If any one is interested for the xls file here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7sUum26xzavRHQ5YkNibUo5WDg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any hidden columns?

Comment: hi @cchristelis, the actual problem is a bit wearied and I don’t have any explanation of it , which is because the excel file was generated by my program in order to fetch all of the cell value(s)  through xlrd I had to modify a single cell (any of the following sheet) every time and only after saving that it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Old question but if anyone comes here via web search:

Remember the xlrd cell is takes arguments in the order of ROW, COLUMN where php for example is COLUMN, ROW. In Python if you are looking at cell(1,116) thats row 1 column 116 and unlikely to have any data in it

also xlrd row index starts at 0

see http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html